# send form data to other server and return pdf

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a very complex form that contains quite some fields (approx 50). The submit process works fine, but I'd like to add a new 'link' that allows a user to get the data he's filled in on a PDF.

I have a simple PDF mechanism set up on another server, but I need to send the form data there, without actually submitting the form on the original server.

How can I do the following:

- send all the form data to another server
- receive a PDF, whilst still staying on the form page and being able to submit that

Comment: That's nice, what did you try?

Comment: actually i'm reading that I can post with Jquery and form.serialize, but I'm really not sure how to get the contents back as a file...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do so is to submit to your own server, and let him process the data to a PDF.
Your server could do an HTTP request to an external server if you wish.
After your server has processed the request and created the PDF, he can generate a link for the client (browser) to download, and you will show it to the user using `Javascript`.

Comment: i can't - on that server I can no longer control the PDF creation - can only add some limited Javascript to the form

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say. You do have access to the server side code, right?

Comment: i need to do this in multiple places and will not always have access over the server side code at the server where the form is - no... so i'd like to pass the form data from there to another server, do something with it and then return and display a file...

Comment: You mean - an external "PDF Creation" service? You should look how to do it, because you can't AJAX a remote server (that isn't the one the JS is run on) - e.g from this website, you cannot AJAX Google.

Comment: yeah - i know, that was the question... what can i use then?

Comment: You'd have to use your own server